# Calculating the surface integral over a charged box

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law

In a question that I'm trying to solve, we're told that there is a box with dimensions 20cm long, 4cm high, and 3cm deep. we're given that the electric field on every surface of the box is pointing vertically upwards, and that the strength on the bottom is 1500 volts/m, over all the sides its 1000V/M, and over the top its 600V/M

we are asked to find the total charge in the box.

I'm assuming I need to use Gauss's law and find the flux through a surface. Am I allowed to just use a plane above the box for this or does it need to be a surface that is closed and fully encompasses the box?

In my calculations I assumed I could just use a plane above the box (since that's where all the field lines are pointing).  so I got: $$\oint \overset{\rightarrow }{E}dA = \frac{q}{\varepsilon _{0}}$$
and since the electric field is perpendicular to the plane its just $$\left |\overset{\rightarrow }{E}   \right |A = \frac{q}{\varepsilon _{0}}$$  where $E = 1000+1500+600= 3100$ and $A = 20cm *3cm = 0.6m$
 giving: $$q = 3100\times 0.6\times\left (  8.85\times10^{-12}\right )$$ (the 8.85 is the value im using for epsilon naught, which I'm not sure if it is right?)which gives $1.6461\times10^{-8}$ which is coming back as incorrect.

I have also trying setting the field strength on the bottom of the box as negative, since the lines are heading into the box, which I think is actually correct, and used the same exact method as above (only, doing it twice and minus-ing the result from the bottom). Still wrong, so I'm guessing there is something more fundamental wrong with my working? If anyone can shed light on where I'm making my mistake I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: You have to use $ \oint \overset{\rightarrow }{E}dA =
\Sigma_{surfaces} E \times$(surface area), since the size of the electric field is different on the different surfaces. It isn't clear from your question whether the electric field is in the *out normal* direction in all cases.

Comment: @jim The field is said to be "pointing upwards" on all faces.  I guess there's still room for interpretation there ...

Comment: Gauss' Law applies to closed surfaces.  You can't use it on open surfaces.

Comment: took it that the box was closed, though the question seems to use just the one face

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, one issue I noticed is the incorrect Gauss' Law expression. It is actually:

$$ \oint {\vec E}\cdot \mathrm{d}{\vec A} = \frac{q}{\epsilon_0}  $$

So only the perpendicular component of the vectors through each face surface matters. Since the electric field vectors for all the voltages you've given across each surface are acting upwards, only the top and bottom faces will contribute to the Gauss' Law expression.

The error as I see it is that you've included the side faces in your evaluation, when there is no electric field acting perpendicular to the respective faces.

The convention here is such that all vectors leaving the Gaussian surface (a cube in this case) are positive and vice versa.
The area of the top and bottom faces is: $ 0.2 \hspace{2 pt}m \times 0.03\hspace{2 pt} m = 0.006 \hspace{2 pt}m^2 $

Applying the values you've given:

$$ q = \epsilon_0[(-1500+600)\times 0.006] = -4.779 \times 10^{-11}  \hspace{3 pt} C$$

I hope this is the answer given, otherwise you could directly post the question and I can give it another go.

Comment: ahh Thank you, that was correct, I had actually got the -4.779 part (eventually), but had made a stupid mistake in converting the surface area of the box to meters, I had $0.6m$ instead of $0.006m^{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Determine the surface element of the cube, 2x2y2z or 8xyz, then use the integral version of Gauss's Law.